# LogTrace and LogDebug Not Appearing in Console OR Debug Windows - Logging issue in .NET 7.0

Tags: c#, debugging, logging, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

I am managing to display logging for the following Level of logs in both the console and debug windows in my ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project.

2. .LogInformation
3. .LogWarning
4. .LogError
5. .LogCritical

However, the two lower value ones ARE NOT displaying

0. LogTrace
1. LogDebug

I have edited the `appsettings.json` to:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

However this has had no effect.

I also tried the following code in `program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();
builder.Logging.AddDebug();
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);

var app = builder.Build();
```

Also to no success!

Any help outputting Trace and Debug to Debug windows and Console window would be appreciate. Can't find the help I need on Google.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you override the settings in appsettings.Development.json ?

Comment: That is where I was going wrong! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you are editing changes the production environment, you need to edit the appsettings.Development.json to work in development environment.

[image: appsettings.Development.json]

Change the "Microsoft.AspNetCore" level to trace and you can see logs in the console as debug is higher than trace.

[image]

Change the "Default" level to debug and you can see logs in debug output. Remember to add debug level service in program.cs through "builder.Logging.AddDebug();"

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That is where I was going wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize there was appsettings.Development.json with the same settings hidden under the main appsettings.json.

This is how my appsettings.Development.json looks now, and all tracing now works as expected.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Settings in .NET Core come from various sources and override previous settings, no matter where they come from. The default web host uses appsettings.json, a domain-specific file, environment variables *and* the command line. You can override a specific debug level by using the correct connection string.